# Cannot install nuget package unity 2

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, unity-container

I need to downgrade my app from 4.5 to 3.5 and i had unity 3 installed. Now i cannot install unity 2.1 from nuget, because of this error:

```
PM> Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\voskresenskiy\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find version '2.1.505.2' of package 'Unity'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Unity -Version 2.1.505.2
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What am i doing wrong? I'll be gratefull for any help

Answer (score 1):

It seems your internet connection ist down or the Nuget Org is temporary not reachable, and the desired version of Unity is not avilable in the cache.

Take alook at [this](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8):

> Though NuGet packages are typically consumed from a remote gallery
>   such as the NuGet gallery using a network connection, there are many
>   scenarios where the client is not connected. Without a network
>   connection, the NuGet client was not able to successfully install
>   packages - even when those packages were already on the client's
>   machine in the local NuGet cache. NuGet 2.8 adds automatic cache
>   fallback to the package manager console. For example, when
>   disconnecting the network adapter and installing jQuery, the console
>   shows the following:
>
> PM> Install-Package jquery The source at nuget.org
>   [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet
>   Local Cache at C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache Installing
>   'jQuery 2.0.3'. Successfully installed 'jQuery 2.0.3'. Adding 'jQuery
>   2.0.3' to WebApplication18. Successfully added 'jQuery 2.0.3' to WebApplication18.

EDIT:

After testing the same command i can confirm it works fine, using the same version i could install it using nuget, check the settings of nuget and ensure the nuget.org is check as package source.

Comment: That sounds a little strange, because i have installed another nuget package without any troubles. It looks like Unity 2 is not presented in Nuget (in it's GUI Manager i see only unity 3 pakage)

Comment: This might be the issue, but i would expect another message than www.nuget.org is unreachable, its kind of wierd message for this case.

Comment: Anyway, what am i to do with this? Is there any trick to install package manually?

Comment: Just install the package via Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for solution. Find the NuGet package and you get the option to select the projects you want to install it for.

Comment: @matt Your comment should be a separate answer. It solved the issue for me.